# what is the equivalent query from mysql to mongosb

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php

im new to mongodb after years with mysql and trying to figure this equivalent query in mongodb with php composer

select * from table where (x > 0 and x < 30) or x = 'half' and sid = 1

```
$query = [
    '$and' => [
        [
     'sid'=> 1
        ], ['$and' => [[
            'info.x' => [
                '$lt' => '30'
            ]
        ], [
            'info.x' => [
                '$gt' => '0'
            ]
        ],  [
            'info.x' => [ /// i want to put this in $or
                'half'
            ]
        ]]
]

    ]
];
```

i want to display all what is greater then 0 and less then 30 or equal to 'half' where sid is 1

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    { "x": { "$gte": 0, "$lte": 30 }},
    { "x": "half" }
  ],
  "sid": 1
})
```

Or

```
$query = [
  '$or'=> [
    [ 'x'=> [ '$gte'=> 0, '$lte'=> 30 ]],
    [ 'x'=> 'half' ]
  ],
  'sid'=> 1
]
```